# Can EAFP and mypy coexist?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, duck-typing

> ### EAFP
>
> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.
>
> [From Python Glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html)

> ### [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy#what-is-mypy)
>
> #### What is mypy?
>
> Mypy is an optional static type checker for Python. You can add type hints ([PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)) to your Python programs, and use mypy to type check them statically. Find bugs in your programs without even running them!
>
> You can mix dynamic and static typing in your programs. You can always fall back to dynamic typing when static typing is not convenient, such as for legacy code.

Here's an awesome YouTube video about EAFP: https://youtu.be/x3v9zMX1s4s

I'm trying to use `mypy`, but it's getting angry basically every time I write some EAFP code.

For example:

```py
from contextlib import suppress

from typing import Optional


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name: Optional[str] = None

    @property
    def name(self) -> Optional[str]:
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name: str):
        self.__name = name

    @property
    def upper_name(self) -> Optional[str]:
        with suppress(AttributeError):
            return self.name.upper()  # Item "None" of "Optional[str]" has no attribute "upper" - mypy(error)
        return None
```

In this example, I want the `upper_name` property to try to convert `name` to uppercase, but in case `name` is `None`, it'll raise an `AttributeError`, that is then suppressed by `suppress(AttributeError)`, so the function returns `None` instead.

I have the explicit `return None` at the bottom because [PEP 8](https://pep8.org#programming-recommendations) says to:

> Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable).

I have submitted this as an [issue (#9467) to the `mypy` repo](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/9467), but it got almost instantly closed.

I do think it'd be possible to have `mypy` understand EAFP.

For example, if it sees a type `Optional[something]`, and it sees an expression that would raise a `SomethingError` if it receives `None`, but succeed if it receives `something`, and that expression is enclosed in a `try` or `suppress` block that can handle `SomethingError`, then it could assume it's some EAFP code, and not freak out.

But the way it is now, to have it not freak out with the example above, I'd have to change it to:

```py
from typing import Optional


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__name: Optional[str] = None

    @property
    def name(self) -> Optional[str]:
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name: str):
        self.__name = name

    @property
    def upper_name(self) -> Optional[str]:
        if self.name is not None:
            return self.name.upper()  # No error here this time
        else:
            return None
```

Another example:

Suppose I can have a `house` that can have a `garage` that can have a `car` that has a `brand`, something like this would allow me to get it's `brand`:

```py
from contextlib import suppress

from my_module import house

car_brand = None
try:
    car = house.garage.car
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    car_brand = car.brand
```

If `house` is `None`, or if its `garage` is `None`, or if its `car` is `None`, `car_brand` will stay `None`. But if there is a `house` with a `garage` with a `car`, it'll try to get its `brand`. If the `car` has no `brand`, that error will not be suppressed, because a `car` MUST have a `brand`.

The other way of doing it, to not have `mypy` erroring, would be:

```py
from my_module import house

car_brand = None
if house is not None:
    garage = house.garage
    if garage is not None:
        car = garage.car
        if car is not None:
            car_brand = car.brand
```

And I don't think that's very readable or clean.

Another point that I believe is valid is avoiding race conditions. If I first read a value to check if it's valid, then read it again to use it if it's valid, I believe there's nothing that guarantees the second time I'm reading it I'll receive the same value as the first time.

With doing things the "EAFP" way, I only read values once, so it doesn't matter if the value changes drastically just after I've read it.

My examples aren't perfect, but I think they do the trick in conveying the idea.

So my question is, how can I use the EAFP style and still use `mypy`? Is there a flag or argument I can give `mypy` so it doesn't freak out in the mere existence of EAFP? Or is there a "better" EAFP way of doing stuff, that doesn't make `mypy` sad?

- **Python** `3.8.6`
- **mypy** `0.782`

Comment: First, instead of either asking for permission or forgiveness, mypy (and static typing in general) encourages you do neither: you design your code so the operation you want to do is guaranteed to 100% succeed. For example, in your case I'd try making `self.name` be of type `str` instead of `Optional[str]` to sidestep the problem completely. If this isn't possible, try doing `if self.name is not None` instead. Mypy _does_ understand this idiom and can deduce `self.name` must be of type str in that code block. This idiom is also more precise since you can control exactly what you're narrowing.

Comment: Second, I think applying EAFP for things like AttributeErrors is a fatal mistake/an abuse of the technique -- those errors are almost always due to a bug in your code and so should never be caught or masked. (And the whole point of using Mypy is so it can catch these sorts of bugs for you). EAFP is better applied for errors that are out of your control. For example, suppose you ask the user for the path to some file. Instead of first checking to see if the file exists before reading it, it'd be better to just try reading it and catch the exception Python will raise if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @Michael0x2a thanks for those insights. On the code I'm working on, I often have nested attributes that I have to access. For example, say that there's a House that optionally has a Garage that optionally has a Car, and I want to know the Car's brand, with EAFP I'd usually try `House.Garage.Car.brand` and catch an `AttributeError`, but with `mypy` I end up having to do `if House is not None:` then `if House.Garage is not None:` then `if House.Garage.Car is not None:` to finally get to `House.Garage.Car.brand`. Is that the recommended way to go about it even in those cases?

Comment: And what about race conditions? I'm pretty new to Python, but I do think I understand the concept behind race conditions, and if I'm not wrong, ideally we should do things straight away and only once, to avoid the possibility of its value changing between each attempt of reading it. If I went straight to `House.Garage.Car.brand`, that'd either give me a brand or not, but if I ask before each step, what guarantees that the House will still have a Garage after I've already asked once if it had one?

Comment: I'd first try restructuring your data so you can avoid having Optional types if possible. For example, maybe you could have `House` contain a list of Room objects instead of hard-coding a Garage field? Or alternatively, restructure your code so it first has a "validation/parsing" state that checks the integrity of your input data and returns a new version that's more sanitized. This phase could throw an exception if the input is missing any required fields, perhaps replace optional ones with some default value, rearrange the output data to have less special cases, and so forth.

Comment: This initial parsing/validation stage may be a bit messy and so may not be worth statically typing. For example, it'd be reasonable to have your data be of type `Any` in this initial phase so you can continue to use the `catch AttributeError` workaround. But you should hopefully be able to contain all this messiness just in this one place and return cleaner data the rest of your code can use without needing to repeat these types of checks. https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/ has a good overview of this style of structuring data and code.

Comment: Regarding race conditions: keep in mind that `House.Garage.Car.brand` is not a single atomic operation in Python. It's actually three, since there are three attribute accesses. For example, `House.Garage` could change to become `None` right before you try evaluating `Garage.Car` or `Car.Brand`. So if you want to avoid a data race here, you'll need to use a lock. EAFP can only prevent data races if the operation you want to perform is guaranteed to be atomic, which it won't necessarily be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! I'll read the suggested article and see what I can do to make my code better.